# Affect of mollifiers on the regularity of the boundary of a domain

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a domain with Lipschitz boundary. Locally the boundary of $\partial \Omega$ is the graph of a Lipschitz function. I take coordinate patches and in each coordinate patch make a convolution with a standard mollifier to make the boundary smooth. I believe that the bound on the Lipschitz constant of the boundary remains unchanged. Also, this family of smooth domains are uniformly Lipschitz. How one can rigorously prove it?